# How can resolve this issue file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty?

Tags: laravel, xero-api

I am using XERO API to integrate with my project, while authentication i am using consumer_key, consumer_secret, rsa_private_key, rsa_public_key to authenticate with xero account, i was generate **rsa_private_key**  and **rsa_public_key** and placed in storage/app/certificates directory while fetching these keys i am using file_get_contents function to get the keys but facing the error **file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty**, how can i resolve this?

> My File paths

[image]

> Xero.php

private static function get_config(){

```
        return $config = [

            'oauth' => [

                'callback'         => '',

                'consumer_key'     => config('constants.XERO_CONSUMER_KEY'),

                'consumer_secret'  => config('constants.XERO_CONSUMER_SECRET'),

                'rsa_private_key'  => file_get_contents(config('constants.XERO_PRIVATE_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH')),

                'rsa_public_key'   => file_get_contents(config('constants.XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH')),

            ],
        ];
    }
```

> config/constants/dev_constants.php

```
<?php

$xero_constants = [
    "XERO_CONSUMER_KEY"     => "***",
    "XERO_CONSUMER_SECRET"  => "***",
    "XERO_PRIVATE_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH"    =>  dirname(__FILE__,3)."/storage/app/certificates/privatekey.pem",
    "XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH"     =>  dirname(__FILE__,3)."/storage/app/certificates/publickey.cer",

];

?>
```

Comment: Is the error being thrown because it cant read the key files ??? you could use `storage_path('app/certificates/privatekey.pem)` helper method instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @alithedeveloper It is not working!

Comment: @alithedeveloper this command can create issue i think.. How can i overcome it?
'rsa_public_key'   => file_get_contents(config('constants.XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH')),

Comment: Can you `dd(config('constants.XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH'))`. I think you are reading the config wrong. It should be `config('constants.dev_contants. XERO_PRIVATE_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH')` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are yting to get config via :

```php
config('constants.XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH')
```

It will return `null`. because config has no `return`. You need to edit your `dev_constants.php` :

```php
<?php

return [
    "XERO_CONSUMER_KEY"     => "***",
    "XERO_CONSUMER_SECRET"  => "***",
    "XERO_PRIVATE_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH"    =>  dirname(__FILE__,3)."/storage/app/certificates/privatekey.pem",
    "XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH"     =>  dirname(__FILE__,3)."/storage/app/certificates/publickey.cer",

];
```

```php
config('constants.dev_constants.XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH')
```

Comment: I have edited @wahyu answer, but looking at your config structure it should be `config('constants.dev_constants.XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH')`

Comment: @alithedeveloper you cannot edit someone's answer based on your answer. You can answer it. You can edit someone's answer because of typo, format or broken links.

Comment: My bad, didnt know that. However, it was adding just `dev_constants` to your config read.